# WebTesting using VSTS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, webtest

I've been trying to create and execute webtests for one of my websites using VSTS 2008 SP1. The problem is that during playback VSTS does not play back the javascript. How can i solve this and where can I find comprehensive information on configuring VSTS to do web tests exactly as i want.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately webtests work on a request response basis and only validate based on the contents of those. VSTS is not going to be able to run the javascript in the context of the returned html response.

It is theoretically possible to instanciate a browser object from your coded webtest and feed it the returned html+javascript and check modifications made to the html after that, but I don't see that would really end happily.

The "correctness" of your Javascript is also highly browser dependant, so you really need to test this on each of the browsers you require. Like Css and look and feel, this is still going to require manual testing.

However, Visual Studio 2010 now has a [coded UI test](http://blogs.msdn.com/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/06/12/automated-user-interface-testing-with-coded-ui-test.aspx) that will allow you to test your pages in the way you want.